# Expected T, got Object in Vue-Prop of custom Object-Type

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, bit.dev

#### Description

Hello there,

I would like to share my Vue-components using bit.dev.

I got a Vue-component like this:

```
<template>
    ...
</template>

<script>

import CustomItem from "../../../../objects/CustomItem";

export default {
    name: "Test",
    props: {
        item: {
            type: CustomItem,
        },
    },
};
</script>
```

As you can see, this component requires the prop to be a specific object.

This is the `CustomObject`

```
export default class CustomItem {
    constructor ({id, name}) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

   // provide cool functions here
}
```

This works fine in my project, but not if I include this this way:

```
<template>
    <div v-if="!$wait.is('item.loading')">
        <MyComponent :item="item"/>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import MyComponent from '@bit/myproject.my-component'
import CustomItem from '@bit/myproject.custom-item';

export default {
    name: 'Home',
    components: {MyComponent},
    data () {
        return {
            item: {}
        };
    },
    beforeRouteEnter (to, _from, next) {
        const promises = [
            axios.get (`/api/item/1`)
        ];

        next (vm => {
            vm.$wait.start ('item.loading');
            axios.all (promises)
            .then (([itemRes]) => {
                vm.item = new CustomItem(itemRes.data.data);
            }).finally(()=>{
                vm.$wait.end ('item.loading');
            });
        });
    },
};
</script>
```

In this case I get this error:

```
[Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "item". Expected T, got Object 

found in

---> <MyComponent> at resources/js/components/Items/MyComponent.vue
```

What did I miss here?

### Edit

As I can see, the component `@bit/myproject.my-component` which has been provided by bit.dev, provides a packed and minified version of my component. In there, the prop looks like this:

```
props:{item:{type:function t(e){var n=e.id,r=e.name})...
```

So I guess this is why this happens.

Answer (score 2):

Basically it seems that in your project actually there are 2 classes `CustomItem`:

- the one you imported relatively:

```
import CustomItem from "../../../../objects/CustomItem";
```

- and the one you imported as an external package:

```
import CustomItem from '@bit/myproject.custom-item';
```

So I would try first to check if it works when you unify your imports to one form:

```
import CustomItem from '@bit/myproject.custom-item';
```

But is JS world things are not simple sometimes and even this may not help you - sometimes even referring to `CustomItem` in this way does not guarantee that there won't be more than one `CustomItem` in your production codebase. The solution I would suggest is to enforce ['duck-typing'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) in [a custom props validator](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#props), if it's really important to check the type of the prop. You still cannot use JS [instanceof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof) as it won't work, even checking `item.prototype.name === 'CustomItem'` is not a good idea, as class names are changed during code minimalization, so duck-typing seems to be the only reasonable solution for you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I updated my question, because I found the "T" in the compiled shared bit-module. So I guess I really have to do some "duck typing".